# Active state of buttons in Titanium

Tags: android, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I've following TSS style for Appcelerator Titanium Button
(styles/app.tss):

```
"Button[platform=android]": {
 font: {
    fontFamily: "skater"
  }
}
"Button": {
    color: "#ece804",
    backgroundColor: "#4076d0",
    backgroundSelectedColor: "#ffffff",
    selectedColor: "#000",
    borderRadius: 20,   
}
```

What I want to achieve:
button in default state has yellow collor and blue background (container also have blue background).
When button is clicked, I want to change background to white and text color to blue (and this is not happening - I am not sure why).

Also, I am not sure how to make background of the button less "sharpy" ( I am not sure how to describe this, just look at the picture):
[image: application screenshot]

How can I:

1. make active button text color blue?
2. make background border radius more "antialiased"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) put an event listener to `touchStart` and `touchEnd` event :

```
yourButton.addEventListener('touchStart',function(e){
        e.source.color="blue";
});
yourButton.addEventListener('touchEnd',function(e){
        e.source.color="#ece804";
});
```

2) it is not clear what you really want...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In 2) I meant that white, rounded "hover" background is too sharpy on its edges - is there possibility to make it more "antialiased"?

Comment: Also, how can I use it for all buttons across the application?

Comment: to use this across the app you have to wrap this button in a widget.

Comment: This answer is somewhat correct. However there is no caps. With caps when I tried it, it never worked.